# Swift : show subview with animation on click of button

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, animation, uiviewanimation

I want to make subview hidden false when user presses button. This subview has opacity with 60% set at design time. The subview should appear with smooth animation beginning from location where button is present.

[image: Screenshot for question]

Below is code that I've tried :

```
 @IBAction func moreOptions_Clicked(sender: AnyObject) { print("moreOptions clicked")

  UIView.animateWithDuration(0.9, delay: 0.2, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionCurlDown, animations: {
      //self.objMoreView.hidden = false
      // Show view with animation
  }, completion: nil)}
```

This didn't worked. Any solution?

Comment: try `alpha = 0` then hide it on completion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `.hidden = false` by `.alpha = 1` and it should work ;)

Explanation :

*If you wanna animate the "visibility" of your UI object :*

Set your **alpha initial value at 0** (your object will be "hidden")
During your animation, **set its value to 1**, the `UIView.animateWithDuration()` will animate the 0 -> 1 change by passing by all values during the duration. You will have a animation which show your subview progressively.

*If you wanna animate the position or the size of your UI object :*

`yourObject.frame.size.(height or width)`

or

`yourObject.frame.origin.(x or y)`

Hope I helped you.

Comment: I updated my answer, maybe it could be more detailed.

Comment: For members who have the same problem, if the answer is the solution do not hesitate to validate it. It could help them ;p

Comment: That helped but it is showing completely i.e. subview comes as entire. I want subview to come from top right corner slowly and should finish  it with some duration (say 10 seconds)

Comment: Okay so you have to be more precise ! How exactly do you imagine your animation ? By changing the frame ? The position ? Just consider that the UIView.animateWithDuration() update your view properties during the time you defined. So, in this function, if you wanna move your view (for example) from the right to the left, you just have to set yourSubview.frame.origin.x property :)

Comment: In your case (if I understand it correctly), your initial values should be : x = self.view.frame.size.width --- y = self.view.frame.origin.y. Then, during your animation, you set both of them with the values you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with constraints. 
For instance set a top constraint to your button in your view. 
Keep a reference to that constraint :

```
self.whatEverTopButtonConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.whatEverButton, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.whatEverSubView, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
self.whatEverSubView.addConstraint(self.whatEverTopButtonConstraint)
```

then whenever you want to make the button appears, set the constant of this constraint to whatever you need.
Finally just animate it with a nice spring effect. It would result to something like this :

```
    func showButton () {
        self.whatEverTopButtonConstraint.constant = 20 //custom the right constraint constant here
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.9, delay: 0.2, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: {
        self.whatEverButton.alpha = 1
        self.whatEverSubView.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
    }
```

Of course this code will animate the position only vertically. If you wish to make it move at the same moment horizontally, set a constraint from the right edge for instance, and then just before the call of the animation set its constant ;)